# Changing a non-recursive method into recursive one

Tags: java, recursion

I have two non-recursive methods, one of them reads the total "e" chars inside a string, another one checks if an ArrayList is alphabetical or not.

```
public static int counter( String str ) {
      int k = 0;
      for( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
         if( str.charAt(i) == 'e' || str.charAt(i) == 'E' ) {
            k++;
         }
      }
      return k;
   }
```

```
public static boolean isAlpha( ArrayList<String> words ) {
      int n = 0;
      if ( words.isEmpty() ) {
         return false;
      } else if ( words.size() == 1 ) {
         return true;
      }
      while( n < (words.size() - 1) ){
         int j = words.get(n).compareTo( words.get(n + 1));
         if ( j > 0 ) {
            return false;
         }
         n++;
      }
      return true;
   }
```

The definition of recursive method is that the method calls itself. I do believe that I understand the concept, however it is really hard to implement or convert it to recursive method. How can I turn these method into recursive one and while doing it how should I think?
Also, here is my another method which prints out numbers with specified digit-size size only.

```
public static void printN( int n, int step ) {
      if ( step > Math.pow( 10, n - 1 ) - 1 ) {
         if ( step < Math.pow( 10, n ) - 1 ) {
            if ( step % 2 == 0 ) {
               if ( condition( step )) {
                  System.out.print( step + " " );
               }
            }
         }
      }
      if ( step >= Math.pow( 10, n ) ) {
         return;
      }
      printN( n, step + 1 );
   }
```

the condition method checks if the first digit - from right - of a number is greater than the second one, and checks again if second one is greater than the third one. This checking process continues until it reaches the last digit. Is it possible to write printN "method" with only parameter value of "int n"? Plus the "counter" method in a recursive way with only one parameter value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing to consider when writing a recursive function/method is when to return from the method.

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(counter("He She They", 0));

        System.out.println(isSortedAlphabatically(List.of("Hello", "World")));
        System.out.println(isSortedAlphabatically(List.of("Good", "Hello", "World")));
        System.out.println(isSortedAlphabatically(List.of("Morning", "Good", "World")));
        System.out.println(isSortedAlphabatically(List.of("Good", "Bad", "Morning", "Evening", "Poor", "Rich")));
        System.out.println(isSortedAlphabatically(List.of("Bad", "Evening", "Good", "Morning", "Poor", "Rich")));
        System.out.println(isSortedAlphabatically(null));
        System.out.println(isSortedAlphabatically(List.of()));
    }

    public static int counter(String str, int count) {
        if (str.isEmpty()) {
            return count;
        }
        if (str.charAt(0) == 'e' || str.charAt(0) == 'E') {
            // Call the function recursively with the substring starting from index 1 and
            // count + 1
            return counter(str.substring(1), count + 1);
        }
        // Call the function recursively with the substring starting from index 1
        return counter(str.substring(1), count);
    }

    public static boolean isSortedAlphabatically(List<String> words) {
        if (words == null || words.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (words.size() == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return words.get(0).compareTo(words.get(1)) > 0 ? false
                : isSortedAlphabatically(words.subList(1, words.size()));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3
true
true
false
false
true
false
false
```